# Asp.net WebApi multipart/form-data with id from route definition

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm sending a multipart/form-data request to an action (file upload), but I'm sending it to an action that has the id in the url as specified by the route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{action}",
    defaults: new {action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Url I'm posting to: `/api/Contacts/1/Photo`

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Photo(int id)
{

    var task = this.Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    task.Wait();
    Stream requestStream = task.Result;

    /* ... */

}
```

With the id parameter, I get this error: `No 'MediaTypeFormatter' is available to read an object of type 'Int32' with the media type 'multipart/form-data'.` Without the id parameter, it works fine.

I tried a MediaTypeFormatter in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10039092/400861), but it doesn't seem to get the id from the url and crashes when trying to get it using `FirstDispositionNameOrDefault("id")`. Is there a way to get the id specified in the route url to bind to the id parameter for the action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FirstDispositionNameOrDefault is for reading the values of form controls.

You can use the [FromUri] attribute on the parameter:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Photo([FromUri] int id)
```

This tells Web API not to get the parameter from the message body.

Comment: +1. Thanks. Yet surely the formatter error is **really misleading**. The problem is not the formatter but seems to be on resolving the action?