# What's the proper way to declare Collection<bool> object and of different datatype?

Tags: c#, .net

What's the proper way to use Collection object & of different datatype?

I'm getting `type or namespace Collection<bool> could not be found` error.  Also found that member variable `_isFormData` is both bool, int and string at once.  :-/

Saw this example, under accepted answer, at [Web API: how to access multipart form values when using MultipartMemoryStreamProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072767/web-api-how-to-access-multipart-form-values-when-using-multipartmemorystreampro)

```
private Collection<bool> _isFormData = new Collection<bool>();  //bool...

_isFormData.Add(String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName));  //string...

for (int index = 0; index < Contents.Count; index++)
{
   if (_isFormData[index]) //int...
   { }
}
```

Comment: There is no `Collection<T>` type in `System.Collections.Generic` namespace, what type of collection do you want? `List<bool>` perhaps?

Comment: It's never a `string` or `int`.  `String.IsNullOrEmpty` returns `bool` and you use an `int` to index the collection to pull out a `bool` value in `_isFormData[index]`.  And you probably are missing a `using System.Collections.ObjectModel`.

Comment: @BenRobinson [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @juharr: Ah!  It all make sense now.  It was confusing at first and Object Browser in Visual Studio returned no hit when I used "Collection".   It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a `using  System.Collections.ObjectModel;` line for the type to referenced correctly in your class.

The type is only ever a collection of booleans:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition.FileName)
```

tests whether `contentDisposition.FileName` is `null` or `""` and returns true if so; false otherwise.

```
isFormData[index]
```

returns the bool value in the collection at element `index`.

Comment: Actually it's just `using  System.Collections.ObjectModel`.

Comment: Ah! It all make sense now. It was confusing at first and Object Browser in Visual Studio returned no hit when I used "Collection" keyword search. It works now.  Now stuck waiting 5 more minutes for StackOverflow to let me accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to get you started. Note the "using System.Collections.ObjectModel"

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class Program
{
   public static void Main (String[] args)
   {
       IList<Boolean> testCollection = new Collection<Boolean>();
       testCollection.Add(false);
       testCollection.Add(true);
       FillCollection(testCollection);

       for (int index = 0; index < testCollection.Count; index++)
       {
           if (testCollection[index])
           {
               Console.WriteLine("testCollection[{0}] is true", index);
           }
           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("testCollection[{0}] is false", index);   
           }
       }
   }

   public static void FillCollection (IList<Boolean> collection)
   {
       Random random = new Random();
       for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
       {
           Boolean item = Convert.ToBoolean(random.Next(0, 2));
           collection.Add(item);
       }
   }
}
```