# Encryption through Ionic

Tags: c#, ionic-framework, asp.net-web-api

I had first created a web application in VB.Net. Now i am creating its mobile application using Ionic framework.

While Working with VB.Net, we had an inbuilt encryption decryption algorithm. Now working with Ionic i can't use that dll. So how can i encrypt my login URL which consist of login password and send it to API?

I tried encrypting the password with AES256 but on API side when i decrypt it, the string is not in a correct format. What could be the issue?

Comment: Send byte array by stream

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send image to WebApi service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367834/send-image-to-webapi-service)

Comment: @matt : Brother i have changed the previous question to something else, because i am blocked to ask questions. So please go through this question and please if you can help me out or do you know who can help me through this?

Comment: @Reniuz : I have edited the question. Please go through and if you can help me out..

Comment: @Z3RP : I have edited the question. Please go through and if you can help me out..

Comment: @TausifKhan When u work with passwords its bad when you can deyrpt the hash. You can use bcrypt i think that is a very good algo

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `anchor` then link the `button` to the anchor.
Example

```html
    <a name="firstsection"></a>
    
    
      <a href="#firstsection">First Section</a><br>
     <a href="#secondsection">second Section</a><br>
      <a href="#thirdsection">Third Section</a><br>
      
      
    <div class ="firstsection"> Content XXX<br>
    Content XXX<br>Content XXX<br>
    Content XXX<br>
    Content XXX<br>
    Content XXX<br>
    Content XXX<br>
    Content XXX<br>
    
    Content XXX<br>
    Content XXX<br>
    Content XXX<br>
    Content XXX<br>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    </div>
    <a name="secondsection"></a>
    <div class="secondsection"> ContentYYYY <br>
     ContentYYYY <br>
      ContentYYYY <br>
       ContentYYYY <br>
        ContentYYYY <br>
         ContentYYYY <br>
          ContentYYYY <br>
            ContentYYYY <br>
              ContentYYYY <br>
                ContentYYYY <br>
                  ContentYYYY <br>
                    ContentYYYY <br>
          
    
    
    
    
    
    
    </div>
    <a name="thirdsection"></a>
    <div class="secondsection"> ContentZZZZ<br>
    ContentZZZZ<br>
    ContentZZZZ<br>
    ContentZZZZ<br>
    ContentZZZZ<br>
    ContentZZZZ<br>
    ContentZZZZ<br>
    ContentZZZZ<br>
    ContentZZZZ<br>
    ContentZZZZ<br>
    ContentZZZZ<br>
    ContentZZZZ<br>
    
    
    
    
    
    </div>
    
    <a href="#firstsection">First Section</a><br>
     <a href="#secondsection">second Section</a><br>
      <a href="#thirdsection">Third Section</a><br>
```

Notice how I used `<a name ="firstsection">` for the first part and then calling it again using `<a href="firstsection"> First Section </a>`
and so on for two other part `DIV`
Hope this help.