# How to read an image and text value in C#?

Tags: c#, function, azure, post

[image]

As you can see, I am trying to send an image, and a name through a POST command to a local function.

How Can I read both of these parameters in C#?

This is what I have tried but It can only read File Image.

```
   [FunctionName("Test")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> 
     Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = 
 null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    //Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
    if (!req.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
    }


  foreach (var stream in contents.Contents)
    {


        try
        {
            var fileBytes = await stream.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            var fileinfo = new FileInfo(stream.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('"'));



         //Can Read File image like this.


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return req.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, e);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a workaround to do this like using memory stream?

According to your requirement, I assumed that you could use [HttpContentMultipartExtensions.ReadAsMultipartAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944544(v=vs.118).aspx) and you would get the `MultipartMemoryStreamProvider`, then you could leverage the following code for reading your uploaded files:

```
var multipartMemoryStreamProvider= await req.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();
foreach (HttpContent content in multipartMemoryStreamProvider.Contents)
{  
   // for reading the uploaded file
   var filename= content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Trim('"');
   var stream=await content.ReadAsStreamAsync();          

   //for formdata, you could check whether `content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName` is empty
   log.Info($"name={content.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name},value={await content.ReadAsStringAsync()}");
}
```

Moreover, you could follow this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723064/webapi-formdata-upload-to-db-with-extra-parameters) about creating your custom MultipartFormDataMemoryStreamProvider based on `MultipartMemoryStreamProvider`. And this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072767/web-api-how-to-access-multipart-form-values-when-using-multipartmemorystreampro) about building custom InMemoryMultipartFormDataStreamProvider based on `MultipartStreamProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider`

1. Use `FileData` property to get the posted files
2. Use `FormData` property to get the values of any form data posted based upon the key.

Check this [File Upload and Multipart MIME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2).

Comment: I have to save the files to App folder using this method. Is there a workaround to do this like using memory stream?