# How to interpret multipart/form-data in an ASP.Net controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I am receiving an email as an HTTP POST to my URL.  The controller code is as follows:

```
public void Post(System.Net.Http.Formatting.FormDataCollection formData)
{
    ...
}
```

When sending a simple text email to the URL, everything works fine: the entire email is in formData, broken out into its parts.

However, when I send an email with embedded images and attachments, I get a
"415 Unsupported Media Type" error.

The messages are as follows:

"Message": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'FormDataCollection' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.

How do I receive this message in the Post function?

(the format of messages it can receive is x-www-form-urlencoded as versus form-data)

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036445/how-does-one-correctly-implement-a-mediatypeformatter-to-handle-requests-of-type

Comment: *How* are you sending data by POST, exactly?

Comment: Im not sure that I am. I am sending an email to a server. The server routes the email to my URL.  The URL tunnels under my firewall and repeats the process (signal) with my localhost port.  The listener to the signal reports to me on another port that a POST occured (as versus, say, a GET). The post function in my controller is called when the item comes in, and the argument to the post function has all the information in the item when it hits the breakpoint I put in the code. That is how everything is happening..